# Como carregar imagem do FileUpload para tag <asp:Image>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Minha dúvida é como carregar a imagem direto do *FileUpload* para a tag `<asp:Image>`

E se é possivel fazer essas validações pelo **client side** e fazer as validações de tipo e tamanho via jQuery.

Segue código:

```
 <div id="img2" style="width: 530px; height: 270px; border: 2px solid rgb(225, 226, 233); box-shadow: rgb(246, 246, 249) 0px 0px 5px inset; background-color: rgba(251, 235, 235, 0.4);">
 <asp:Image ID="imgBanner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/" Style="border-width: 0px; position: inherit; min-height: 130px; min-width: 130px; top: 20px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 130px; max-height: 130px;" />
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload"  runat="server"  />
```

que vai resultar nesses componentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente para trazer um `preview` de uma imagem conforme escolhe de `input file`, utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) com [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader) é o ***seguinte***:

```js
$("#foto").on('change', function() {
  if (this.files[0].type.indexOf("image") > -1) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#img1').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  } else {
    $('#img1').attr('src', '');
    alert('Não é uma imagem válida');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" accept="image/*">
<div style="display:table">
  <img id="img1" name="img1" border="0" />
</div>
```

Observação:

- nessa linha `if (this.files[0].type.indexOf("image") > -1) {` verifica se o item é uma imagem.

e no seu código:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="img2" style="width: 530px; height: 270px; border: 2px solid rgb(225, 226, 233); box-shadow: rgb(246, 246, 249) 0px 0px 5px inset; background-color: rgba(251, 235, 235, 0.4);">
        <asp:Image ID="imgBanner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/" Style="border-width: 0px; position: inherit; min-height: 130px; min-width: 130px; top: 20px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 130px; max-height: 130px;" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" accept="image/*" runat="server" />
</form>
<script>
    $("#<%=fileUpload.ClientID%>").on('change', function () {
        if (this.files[0].type.indexOf("image") > -1) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#<%=imgBanner.ClientID%>').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
        else {                
            $('#<%=imgBanner.ClientID%>').attr('src', '');
            alert('Não é uma imagem válida')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Exemplos:

- [Converter imagem para base64 usando VueJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242834/converter-imagem-para-base64-usando-vuejs/242878#242878)
- [Como fazer reset em um input type="file"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246154/como-fazer-reset-em-um-input-type-file/246157#246157)